# Component doesn't receive an event from socket.io

Tags: reactjs, socket.io

I'm building a game. Whenever the first player connects to the server I want him to see a modal that tells him to wait for a second player. In order to trigger the modal I'm trying to tell the component that the first player connected and show him a modal which tells him to wait. The problem is that the component doesn't receive the 'first player connected' event, so I can't trigger the modal. I can see in the console that the event was emitted to a correct room, but it still doesn't work. What is wrong with my code?
Server:

```
var roomno = 0;
var players = 0;
io.on('connection', socket => {
players++;
if(io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms["room-"+roomno] && 
io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms["room-"+roomno].length > 1)
roomno++;
socket.join("room-"+roomno);


io.sockets.in("room-" + roomno).emit('connectToRoom', roomno);

if(players % 2 == 0) {
moves[roomno] = Array(9).fill(null);
socket.to('room-' + roomno).emit('friend connected')
}

if(players % 2 !== 0) {
socket.to('room-' + roomno).emit('first player connected')
console.log('sending event to room-' + roomno)
}
```

Component:

```
componentWillMount() {
this.socket.on('first player connected', () => {
  alert('this alert doesnt even get triggered')
  this.setState({
    showModal:true
  })
  wrapper.classList.add('mask');
})
...bla-bla
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that when component is mounted socket was already connected?

Comment: Yes, I guess. Other events in componentWillMount function work, except for this one.

Comment: `socket.to` will send event to everyone except sender. See https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/docs/emit.md

Comment: I just needed to replace it with "io.in". Thanks for helping.